# View all open invitations on Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

There is a consolidated view of all open/unanswered invitations I have received in Apple and iOS calendar, e.g. invitations I can accept/conditionally accept/decline or cancellations as well where I have a link to delete the event from my calendar.

Is there an aquivalent in Outlook? I am asking for Outlook in general as I am using it among different environments (Win/OS X).

Comment: Please provide what version of Outlook you are using as well.  Could make a difference.

Comment: This is too vague. Whom is it "*open/unanswered*" by? Are these invitations you have sent or received?

Comment: @CharlieRB Thank you for asking for clarification. I didn't have in mind that this might be ambiguous and have clarified my question.

Comment: @CheesusCrust I am asking in general (as I am using Outlook in different environments). If this function exists exclusively in specific versions it would be great if this information could be provided within the answer.